# esp32 cant payload localhost response

Tags: localhost, wifi, esp32, arduino-esp32, esp-idf

I have an ESP 32 which is connected to a computer via Wi-Fi and I send data to the computer using the Get method. I have created a localhost on the computer with xampp software. I have placed a file in the host folder with this path: 192.168.3.1.hi.php which echoes a data.
I test in two modes
In the first case, I create a hotspot with a mobile phone and connect the laptop and esp32 to it, and the steps I mentioned work correctly.
In the second case, I connect the laptop and ESP to the same modem. In this case, it cannot read data from hi.php file  and does not receive data from it.

Comment: This issue concerns network setup, not programming. I suggest asking in https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you think it is your ESP32 problem, please post your code to show the IP and the path the ESP32 trying to access to? No one can guess what's going with your current description.